# How can i make a pagination for this table?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I want to have 10 rows on each page in HTML  .
I tried many options but nothing worked in javascript. I'm a beginner and i spent so much time trying to solve this.

> ```
>  function SetupPaginatino(items, wrapper, rows, rows_per_page) {
>         wrapper.innerHtml = " ";
>         let page_count = Math.cell(items.length / rows_per_page)
>         for (let i = 0; i < page_count + 1; i++) {
>             PaginationButton(i);
>             wrapper.appendChild(btn);
>         }
>     }
>
> i tried this  and it didn't work.
> ```

var data= [
{
"name": "Michael",
"age": "30",
"birthdate": "11/10/1989",
},
{
"name": "Mila",
"age": "32",
"birthdate": "10/1/1989",
},
{
"name": "Paul",
"age": "29",
"birthdate": "10/14/1990",
},
{
"name": "Dennis",
"age": "25",
"birthdate": "11/29/1993",
},
{
"name": "Tim",
"age": "27",
"birthdate": "3/12/1991",
},
{
"name": "Erik",
"age": "24",
"birthdate": "10/31/1995",
},

{
"name": "Mark",
"age": "21",
"birthdate": "10/30/1991",
},
{
"name": "Cristi",
"age": "20",
"birthdate": "10/30/2002",
},
{
"name": "Radu",
"age": "31",
"birthdate": "10/30/1990",
},
{
"name": "Sarah",
"age": "17",
"birthdate": "08/11/2005",
},
{
"name": "Anne",
"age": "22",
"birthdate": "10/30/2000",
},
{
"name": "Mark",
"age": "21",
"birthdate": "10/30/1991",
},
{
"name": "Cristi",
"age": "20",
"birthdate": "10/30/2002",
},
{
"name": "Radu",
"age": "31",
"birthdate": "10/30/1990",
},
{
"name": "Sarah",
"age": "17",
"birthdate": "08/11/2005",
},
{
"name": "Anne",
"age": "22",
"birthdate": "10/30/2000",
},
]

$(document).ready(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

```
    var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].birthdate}</td>
                </tr>`
    $("#myTable").append(row);
}
```

});

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <header>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="table.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="table.css" />

    </header>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="myTable"> </tbody>

    </table>

    <div class="pagenumbers" id="pagination"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **jquery HTML table pagination** built-in library code. make sure you edit the table id with "table-demo" and on limit, you may put limit:10

$('#table-demo').paging({limit:5});